# can't find packages

Tags: ros, package, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS. I got a project from previous developer and now i'm trying to compile it. the project uses several dependent packages (such as *eigen, tf* etc.) but it can't find any of them.

I installed ROS according to instructions and I can find these packages in */opt/ros/diamondback/stacks*, but when I try to call *rosmake* or *rosdep* to any of them it fails to find them.

as I understood it searches in */home/username/.ros/rosmake/* when i call *rosmake*, which of course isn't correct. Where should I change it?

this is how it reacts to rosmake:

> ```
> sergey@ubuntu:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry$rosmake tf
> [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['tf']                           
> [ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/sergey/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-0110825-143550
> [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['tf'] to: >[]                                                             
> [ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: >['tf']           
> [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
> ```

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11014/can%27t-find-packages/) by [Sergey](https://answers.ros.org/users/993/sergey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake doesn't search in `$HOME/.ros/rosmake`. It's just the directory it puts some logs in.

I assume that you are using Ubuntu and installed ros with debian packages. If the system cannot find `tf`, I suspect that you installed ros-diamondback-base and not the recommended package ros-diamondback-desktop-full. To fix it, just execute the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full
```

If that doesn't help, something is probably wrong with your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. In that case, can you please post the output of

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1